# Error al cargar .properties (FileNotFoundException) - JSP, Servlets, DataAccess, JBoss, Maven

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jboss, archivo-de-propiedades

Trabajando en un proyecto `JSP` que corre en `JBoss` (Desarrollado en Eclipse), para administrar las dependencias se usa Apache Maven:

Primero tenemos un Servlet (CargaTasasServlet) que hace uso de un **DataAccessManager** para hacer una petición a una base de datos `Oracle`, pero en el DataAccess la aplicación requiere de los datos de dicha base de datos. Para obtener estos datos, él los lee de un archivo `.properties`. El problema está al momento de leer el archivo, ya que la aplicación no lo encuentra.

Lo extraño es que el proyecto encontramos otro **DataAccessManager** distinto al mencionado anteriormente, el cual accede a una base de datos `MySQL`. Ambos **DataAccessManagers** manejan la misma estructura, solo cambia el archivo `.properties` al que consultan. Pero en este último si lo lee correctamente.

Vale la pena aclarar que ambos `.properties` estan en la misma carpeta, lo cual no debería haber problema con la ruta.

Tambien vale la pena mencionar, que intenté agregar los *properties* en un solo archivo, pero al final la aplicación solo sacaba los datos de la base de datos `MySQL` (Como si el archivo no hubiera sido modificado). Esto me hace pensar que sea problema de JBoss.

Finalmente dejo partes del código que mencioné anteriormente.

Constructor de CargaTasasServlet:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public CargaTasasServlet(){
    super();
    DataAccessMaster dam = new DataAccessMaster();
    try {
        operacionesVentanilla = dam.getReporte1UAODAO().obtenerTodos();
        System.out.println(operacionesVentanilla.toString());
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Código del DataAccessMaster.java (**DataAccessManager** de la Base de Datos `Oracle`):

```
public class DataAccessMaster implements DAOManagerMaster {
    private String _url_master = "";
    private String _user_master = "";
    private String _password_master = "";
    private String _SERVER_HOSTNAME = "";

    private MySQL_Reporte1UAODAO reporte1UAODAO = null;

    private Connection connection = null;

    public DataAccessMaster(){
        InetAddress ip;
        try {

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream("data-master-smv.properties"); 
            //La línea anterior genera la excepción
            properties.load(input);

            this._url_master = properties.getProperty("url_master");
            this._user_master = properties.getProperty("user_master");
            this._password_master = properties.getProperty("password_master");
            this._SERVER_HOSTNAME = properties.getProperty("SERVER_HOSTNAME");

            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String adress = ip.getHostName();
            if (adress.equals(_SERVER_HOSTNAME)) {
                setDBConnection();
                System.out.println("-- Base de Datos en PRODUCCION.");
            }
            else {
                setDBConnection();
                System.out.println("-- Base de Datos en PRUEBAS.");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
    /** } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        **/} catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Código del DataAccessMaster.java (**DataAccessManager** de la Base de Datos `MySQL`):

```
public DataAccess() {
        InetAddress ip;
        try {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        input = new FileInputStream("data.properties");
        properties.load(input);

        this._url = properties.getProperty("url");
        this._url_pruebas = properties.getProperty("url_pruebas");
        this._user = properties.getProperty("user");
        this._password = properties.getProperty("password");
        this._SERVER_HOSTNAME = properties.getProperty("SERVER_HOSTNAME");

        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String adress = ip.getHostName();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        if (adress.equals(_SERVER_HOSTNAME)) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, _user, _password);
            System.out.println("-- Base de Datos en PRODUCCION.");
        }
        else {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_url_pruebas, _user, _password);
            System.out.println("-- Base de Datos en PRUEBAS.");
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

La traza de errores:

```
11:01:15,871 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) java.io.FileNotFoundException: data-master-smv.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

11:01:15,874 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

11:01:15,875 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)

11:01:15,876 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)

11:01:15,878 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at co.gov.banrep.dte.data.DataAccessMaster.<init>(DataAccessMaster.java:37)

11:01:15,879 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at co.gov.banrep.dte.logic.xml.CargaTasasServlet.<init>(CargaTasasServlet.java:37)

11:01:15,880 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

11:01:15,881 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

11:01:15,882 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)

11:01:15,884 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

11:01:15,885 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.msc.value.ConstructedValue.getValue(ConstructedValue.java:61)

11:01:15,886 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.naming.ValueManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ValueManagedReferenceFactory.java:49)

11:01:15,888 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:90)

11:01:15,889 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:01:15,890 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

11:01:15,891 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:01:15,893 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)

11:01:15,894 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

11:01:15,895 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

11:01:15,896 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)

11:01:15,897 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85)

11:01:15,899 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57)

11:01:15,900 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55)

11:01:15,901 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99)

11:01:15,903 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78)

11:01:15,904 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72)

11:01:15,905 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1156)

11:01:15,906 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952)

11:01:15,907 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188)

11:01:15,908 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

11:01:15,909 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

11:01:15,910 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

11:01:15,911 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

11:01:15,912 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

11:01:15,913 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

11:01:15,914 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

11:01:15,916 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

11:01:15,917 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

11:01:15,918 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí podemos observar tanto los dos archivos `.properties` (data y data-master-smv). También, los archivos **CargarTasasServlet** y ambos **DataAccess**.

De igual manera los podemos observar desde el File System:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes mostrarnos la estructura de carpetas desde el filesystem para descartar que sea error de importación de tu eclipse?

Comment: PD: si tu proyecto usa maven para compilar deberías decirlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, el archivo `'data-master-smv.properties'`, se movió a la carpeta `"WEB-INF/classes"`.

Por otro lado al cargar el archivo en la clase `DataAccessMaster`, se hizo con el siguiente código:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = DataAccessMaster.class.getResourceAsStream("/data-master-smv.properties");
        properties.load(input);
```

Con estos cambios, el archivo es leído correctamente.

Esto anterior, lo hice basandome en el siguiente post de la comunidad en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413938/filenotfoundexception-with-properties-file