# Tengo un null al usar una ruta relativa al leer un FileInputStream

Tags: java, archivo, java-8, maven, archivo-de-propiedades

Estoy intentando leer un archivo .properties desde una clase que se encuentra en una carpeta difertente a este .properties. Primeramente, he usado otra clase con un main (puebaLogin.java) para ver si las rutas que uso son correctas y éxito!

Usé ruta absoluta para leer este archivo y no me ha dado ningún problema, de igual manera he probado a usar una relativa y todo correcto.

**Ruta absoluta:** "C:\\Usuario\\Documents\\project-web\\src\\main\\config\\local\\application.properties"

**Ruta relativa:** "src/main/config/local/application.properties"

En la clase que quiero implementar esta funcion (login.java) uso la **ruta absoluta** para probar y me funciona. Compilo, ejecuto el tomcat y todo correcto.
Sin embargo al implementar la **relativa**, no :(, compilo, ejecuto el tomcat y obtengo un null.
Saben tal vez a qué se podría deber esto? Estoy usando Servlets y Maven para la compilación. Mi código:

Login.java

```
public void doAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
   Properties properties = new Properties();
//Usando ruta relativa
   try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/main/config/local/application.properties")){ //null
       properties.load(is);
       System.out.println(properties.getProperty("enviroment"));
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }catch(IOException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }

//Usando ruta absoluta
   try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Usuario\\Documents\\project-web\\src\\main\\config\\local\\application.properties")){ //OK
       properties.load(is);
       System.out.println(properties.getProperty("enviroment")); //localhost
   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }catch(IOException e){
       e.printstackTrace();
   }
}
```

La estructura que tengo del proyecto
[image: Estructura]

Error
[image: Valor nulo]

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: que sistema de construccion usas?

Comment: Te refieres al patrón de diseño? Si es así, es mvc

Comment: no, me refiero al sistema de construccion

Comment: Ah, perdón. Es la primera vez que escucho ese termino.  Uso Maven.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al cargar .properties (FileNotFoundException) - JSP, Servlets, DataAccess, JBoss, Maven](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262254/error-al-cargar-properties-filenotfoundexception-jsp-servlets-dataaccess)

Comment: Voy a probar a ver que tal. Aunque ya había probado con getClass().getResourceAsStream("ruta") sin embargo no me habia funcionado

Comment: si no te funciona, intenta con la carpeta de recursos por defecto del standard directory layout de maven

Answer (score 0):

a primera vista, te diría que en la opción ruta absoluta, separas los directorios con barra invertida, lo que me hace suponer que estás en windows, y en la opción ruta relativa, usas barra simple, nunca va a funcionar, a menos que hayas ejecutado la segunda opción en linux.

Comment: Perdón, no me había dado cuenta que dejé la absoluta con una sola barra \ (lo corrijo en la pregunta),  uso doble barra \\ y no tengo problemas (lo puse en el codigo)

Comment: @frann Tal vez yo no esté entendiendo, pero lo que veo es que en el método que tiene la ruta relativa, usas barra no-invertida, como si estuvieses en linux, no lo he probado en windows, pero creo que es lógico que falle, ya que deberías usar barra invertida (si estoy en lo cierto y estas en windows).

Comment: He probado como tu me dices y también me funciona ejecutandolo en un main, pero el problema persiste al desplegar la aplicación en el tomcat y ejecutar la acción que envuelve a esa ruta :(

Comment: Hola @frann, no se si has solucionado tu problema, espero que si, pero si no es así, te sugiero que pruebes, "main/config/local/application.properties", la rutas relativas, se crean a partir de **src**, sin incluirlo (al menos en linux), no se como se me escapó, te pido disculpas..

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente !!   Encontré una manera de solucionar y servía sin embargo el compañero del proyecto en el que estoy me comentó que lo debería hacer estableciendo la ruta en las variables de tomcat(¿?) y luego trayendo el valor de esa variable desde el servlet. He seguido investigando pero no hallo manera.